# How do I place an element relatively to an image using background-image and ::before/::after?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'd like to position an element (using `::before`/`::after`) relative to an image (using `background-image`), but it doesn't seem to work.

If I add `position: absolute` to `&--right::after` will the `&--right` element be the closest parent with position relative?

I mean the element should be in the lower right corner but it appears in the middle. I think it shouldn't be there since I position it relative to its parent?

I was trying to do my best to explain, but English is not my first language. I believe the screenshots I added below will explain better

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  background-color: var(--very-light-cream);
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.header__container {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 7rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 9rem;
}
.header__container ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.header__container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1.8rem;
}
.header__container ul li a {
  color: #232323;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header__container .nav-toggle {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5rem;
  right: 4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header__container .nav-toggle img {
  width: 2.5rem;
  transition: 300ms all ease;
}
.header__container .nav-toggle:hover img {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.header__container .open {
  height: 100vh;
}
.header__container .hidden {
  display: none;
}
.header__hero {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 12rem;
  margin: 6rem 9rem;
}
.header__hero h1 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 120%;
  letter-spacing: 0.01875rem;
}
.header__hero p {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 140%;
  padding: 3rem 0;
}
.header__hero--right {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("/assets/8331.png");
  height: 46.1rem;
  width: 78.8rem;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top-left-radius: 3.13rem;
}
.header__hero--right::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: url("/assets/Vector.png");
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 30rem;
}
.header input[type=text] {
  width: 25rem;
  height: 5.2rem;
}
.header input[type=text]::-moz-placeholder {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
.header input[type=text]::placeholder {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
.header input[type=submit] {
  height: 5.2rem;
  background-color: rgb(60, 75, 166);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 170%; /* 1.9125rem */
  letter-spacing: 0.0125rem;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
  .header__container {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .header__container nav {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 250ms height ease-in-out;
  }
  .header__container ul {
    margin-top: 2.5rem;
  }
  .header__container ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.2rem 0;
  }
  .header__container ul li a {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .header__container ul li a:hover {
    color: #191919;
  }
  .header .nav-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .header .nav-toggle .hidden2 {
    display: none;
  }
}/*
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;700&family=Source+Sans+3:wght@400;700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <div class="header__container">
                <div>
                    <h2>LOGO</h2>
                    <div class="nav-toggle" id="navToggle">
                        <img
                            id="navClosed"
                            class="navIcon"
                            src="https://www.richardmiddleton.me/wp-content/themes/richardcodes/assets/img/hamburger.svg"
                            alt="hamburger menu" />
                        <img
                            id="navOpen"
                            class="navIcon hidden"
                            src="https://www.richardmiddleton.me/wp-content/themes/richardcodes/assets/img/close.svg"
                            alt="close hamburger" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Forum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="header__hero ">
                    <div class="header__hero--left">
                        <h1>Your strategy is only as good as you execute it</h1>
                        <p>Our simple but powerful OKR+ platform turns great strategies into amazing results. And it's free.</p>
                        <form >
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Get Started" />
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header__hero--right">
                       <div class="right-image"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <script src="/js/sctipt.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[The result I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkXlw.png):

[image]

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvcQ8.png):

[image]

position: absolute
position: relative

Comment: Don't worry about your language skills, your question is understandable. There are two problems though: **1.** your HTML has a `</form>` tag, for a form that's never opened which invalidates your HTML, and **2.** your "CSS" is SASS, and the opening `&__hero` selector has no context. Could you please compile your SASS to CSS, and post that in your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you, I added the code in comments below

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend using a wrapper element, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/em8n0ftk/1/. Also, this isn't a forum;  on this occasion I've taken the code posted in your *answer* (below), and then used the [edit] link on the question to add that detail to the question. Please don't use the answer space (below the text that says "*n* Answers" to post edits or comments, those will be down-voted as they're clearly *not answers*.

Comment: Are you sure the image `/assets/Vector.png` doesn't have extra empty space? Also, do you not want to consider SVG for such an asset?

Answer (score 1):

As the image is set as a `background-image`, there is no real need for the pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after`.

You can have multiple `background-image` and set their respective size and position:

```
  background-image: url("https://placehold.co/100x100/orange/white"), url("https://placehold.co/150x100/blue/white"), url("https://placehold.co/600x400");
  background-size: 100px 100px, 150px 100px, cover;
  background-position: bottom left, top right, center;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header__hero--right {
  background-image: url("https://placehold.co/100x100/orange/white"), url("https://placehold.co/150x100/blue/white"), url("https://placehold.co/600x400");
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background-size: 100px 100px, 150px 100px, cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-position: bottom left, top right, center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__hero--right">
</div>
```

Comment: This is okay however some would prefer having distinct instances for all elements and separation between photo-background (content) and UI elements (decoration).